# Compare result of std::distance with an unsigned type

Tags: c++, casting

I wish to compare index of an element in a std::vector to an unsigned value. If I directly compare like;

```
if(std::distance(...)>min_distance) // true for some
```

I just get a warning, but works fine. However, to get rid of the warning, if I cast min_distance to int, I do not get any comparison result (although there is)

```
if(std::distance(...)>(int)min_distance) // never true
```

What is the exact problem?

Comment: How large is your vector? What's the type of std::difference_t on your platform?

Comment: What are the parameters on distance()? A more complete code sample would help diagnosis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
if ( std::abs( std::distance( ... ) ) > min_distance )
```

[`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) returns a signed value.  I am assuming you are trying to get the distance in such a way that `-2` AND `2` would be considered as `2`.  The `abs` function gives you the [absolute value](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) which means that whatever the sign of the input, you always get a positive value back.

Comment: actually, I am sure that distance will return >=0 in my case, since I compare with the beginning and sure that the element is inside. my question is a more general casting problem actually.

Comment: Whats the value of min_distance then?  Surely it is greater than 0?  What compiler are you using?  I can't see why casting to an "int" would cause a problem ... unless min_distance is greater than 2^31 ..

Comment: sth. less than 10, btw i'm using g++

Comment: Alas I don't have G++ to hand but a quick test compiled perfectly under VS2010 :(

Comment: probably `distance()` in your case is returning negative value. debug it properly to have the root cause.

Comment: argh! my mistake, calling distance as distance(iterator,begin), instead of (begin,iterator) which was giving negative

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like `distance` is returning a negative number in some cases. Normally it would cast the int up to unsigned and the negative number would become large enough to be greater than your condition.

In the second case you would be comparing a negative number against the small positive number cast to `int`.

You can test this out by printing the result from `distance` immediately prior to using it in the comparison.

Answer (score 1):

The value returned by `std::distance<It>`<sup>1</sup> is of type `std::iterator_traits<It>::difference_type`, which may be a `std::ptrdiff_t`, a signed type, hence the warning when trying to compare it with an unsigned type.

C++20 introduced some helpers, like `std::cmp_greater`, defined in header `<utility>`<sup>2</sup>, which

> Compare the values of two integers t and u. Unlike builtin comparison operators, negative signed integers always compare less than (and not equal to) unsigned integers: the comparison is safe against lossy integer conversion.

---

<sup>1) https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance</sup> 
<sup>2) https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/intcmp</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The `std::distance` returns number of increments needed to go from first to last, and it may return negative value if random-access iterators are used and first is reachable from last ([see details](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance)).

For the pointer arithmetic `std::ptrdiff_t` type is used ([see details](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/ptrdiff_t)). And you should keep it in mind, when comparing with `int` value.